# How to get position of object when using feature detection?

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, aforge

I am a new programmer in Emgucv (c#) and I need some help.

I try to use feature detect and follow the example (Emgu->emgucv-windesktop 4.0.1.3373 -> Emgu.CV.Example -> FeatureMatching). It uses Kaze detector to find feature.

I run the example,the result is good. (Can detect feature and give the feature region)

However, I try to change the image (new model image and observe image which crop from model image)

New result can detect feature but the feature region is not correct.

I try to use both color image and gray image (already change ImreadModes.ImageType ).

The region is still not correct.

So, could someone give me guidance or solution?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Draw the model image and observed image, the matched features and homography projection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modelImage">The model image</param>
    /// <param name="observedImage">The observed image</param>
    /// <param name="matchTime">The output total time for computing the homography matrix.</param>
    /// <returns>The model image and observed image, the matched features and homography projection.</returns>
    public static Mat Draw(Mat modelImage, Mat observedImage, out long matchTime)
    {
        Mat homography;
        VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints;
        VectorOfKeyPoint observedKeyPoints;
        using (VectorOfVectorOfDMatch matches = new VectorOfVectorOfDMatch())
        {
            Mat mask;
            FindMatch(modelImage, observedImage, out matchTime, out modelKeyPoints, out observedKeyPoints, matches,
               out mask, out homography);

            //Draw the matched keypoints
            Mat result = new Mat();
            Features2DToolbox.DrawMatches(modelImage, modelKeyPoints, observedImage, observedKeyPoints,
               matches, result, new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255), new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255), mask);

            #region draw the projected region on the image

            if (homography != null)
            {
                //draw a rectangle along the projected model
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, modelImage.Size);
                PointF[] pts = new PointF[]
                {
              new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Bottom),
              new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Bottom),
              new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Top),
              new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Top)
                };
                pts = CvInvoke.PerspectiveTransform(pts, homography);

                Point[] points = new Point[pts.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
                    points[i] = Point.Round(pts[i]);

                using (VectorOfPoint vp = new VectorOfPoint(points))
                {
                    CvInvoke.Polylines(result, vp, true, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 5);
                }
            }
            #endregion

            return result;

        }
    }
}
```

}

Example result : https://www.img.in.th/image/E9RweT

Gray image result : https://www.img.in.th/image/E9RmQQ

Color image result : https://www.img.in.th/image/E9RlFJ